# Create mysql db from json data

Tags: mysql, json

I'm reading JSON data from an ARC Server report online and trying to create a database with the data.
I've created the database named: test.db

I need the columns to be identified as "Service", "Folder", "Service URL", "Configured State", "Real Time State", "Server Type".
and the rows as each "Service" returned from the report.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{"reports": [{
  "folderName": "/",
  "serviceName": "SampleWorldCities",
  "type": "MapServer",
  "description": "The SampleWorldCities service is provided so you can quickly and easily preview the functionality of the GIS server. Click the thumbnail image to open in a web application. This sample service is optional and can be deleted.",
  "isDefault": false,
  "isPrivate": false,
  "hasManifest": false,
  "status": {
    "configuredState": "STARTED",
    "realTimeState": "STARTED"
  },
  "instances": {
    "folderName": "/",
    "serviceName": "SampleWorldCities",
    "type": "MapServer",
    "max": 1,
    "busy": 0,
    "free": 1,
    "initializing": 0,
    "notCreated": 0,
    "transactions": 72,
    "totalBusyTime": 127611,
    "isStatisticsAvailable": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "maxRecordCount": "1000",
    "filePath": "${AGSSERVER}/framework/etc/data/WorldCities/WorldCities.msd",
    "cacheOnDemand": "false",
    "useLocalCacheDir": "true",
    "outputDir": "/home/ec2-user/arcgis/server/usr/directories/arcgisoutput",
    "virtualOutputDir": "/rest/directories/arcgisoutput",
    "supportedImageReturnTypes": "MIME+URL",
    "minScale": "295000000",
    "isCached": "false",
    "ignoreCache": "false",
    "maxScale": "4000",
    "clientCachingAllowed": "true",
    "cacheDir": "/home/ec2-user/arcgis/server/usr/directories/arcgiscache"
  },
  "iteminfo": {
    "description": "The SampleWorldCities service is provided so you can quickly and easily preview the functionality of the GIS server. Click the thumbnail image to open in a web application. This sample service is optional and can be deleted.",
    "summary": "The SampleWorldCities service is provided so you can quickly and easily preview the functionality of the GIS server. Click the thumbnail image to open in a web application. This sample service is optional and can be deleted.",
    "tags": [
      "sample",
      "map",
      "service"
    ],
    "thumbnail": "thumbnail.png"
  },
  "permissions": [{
    "principal": "esriEveryone",
    "permission": {"isAllowed": true},
    "childURL": null,
    "operation": null
  }]
}]}
```

my sript is as follows:

```
import json
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
traffic = json_read
c = db.cursor()

someitem = traffic.itervalues().next()
columns = ['Service', 'Folder', 'Service URL', 'Configured State', 'Real Time State', 'Server Type']

c.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE " \
        "Service='Services' AND type = 'table'")
create_table_string = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]

c.execute('''create table Services
        (Service text primary key,
        Folder text,
        Service URL text,
        Configured State text,
        Real Time State text,
        Server Type text)''')

for service, data in traffic.iteritems():
    services = (service,) + tuple(data[c] for c in columns)
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute(query)
    c.close()


print "JSON Complete"
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Forgot to mention
Service is Service Name,
Folder is folder name,
service url is link to the service,
configured state is configuredState,
realtime state is realTimeState,
Server type is type

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
db = sqlite3.connect(
                'server.db')

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists Services")
db.commit()

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists Services2")
db.commit()

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE Services
                (Service text,
                Folder text,
                Service_URL text,
                Configured_State text,
                Real_Time_State text,
                Server text);''')
```

This was the code that gave me the output I was looking for.